# Syntastic not working in gVim windows7

Tags: windows, vim, syntastic

I have installed syntastic on gVim using pathogen. I can access syntastic documentation and stuff. But syntastic can't check my files for error. I have setup the path for php even then it wont check

Here is the screenshot of errors- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aB7P.png

Answer (score 2):

After dong lots of googling I figured out the answer myself. The E484 error in VIM refers to the case when Vim is unable to execute system level commands, like creating temp files, directories etc.

To check this run `echo system("echo hello")`

In my case I couldn't run this successfully. So I went through my _vimrc and found that somewhere I was setting `set shell=/bin/bash` -> On a windows machine

After this the fix was simple. I just set the shell as 
`set shell=%System32%\cmd`

Hope this helps anyone who is experience this kind of problem.